# Fragment error using create-react-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to publish to npm a React component I created , so I found about the create-react-library and is my first time that I'm using it , I'm trying to test my component from the test folder that it comes with the create-react-library and it compiles successfully but my browser is showing

> Fragment is not defined

when I use the **<> </>** fragments of React

the **package.json** of the Test folder look like this:

```
{
  "name": "example-component",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ../node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "node ../node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build",
    "test": "node ../node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js test",
    "eject": "node ../node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "example-component": "file:..",
    "react": "file:../node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "file:../node_modules/react-dom",
    "react-scripts": "file:../node_modules/react-scripts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

and the **package.json** of the component folder :

```
{
  "name": "example-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "example",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "ManuelMartinDev/example-component",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "start": "microbundle-crl watch --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "prepare": "run-s build",
    "test": "run-s test:unit test:lint test:build",
    "test:build": "run-s build",
    "test:lint": "eslint .",
    "test:unit": "cross-env CI=1 react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "cd example && npm install && npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d example/build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use <React.Fragment> instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long answer, CRL doesn’t have support for the short syntax of fragments, you need to use React.Fragment https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library/issues/243

Answer (score 3):

1.can you try to add 
a. import * as React from 'react'
or 
b. import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
(number 2 is better option)

1. did you try to use "< div>" or <React.Fragment> ?(as warrpers)
2. also i found this answer can you try it ?
   https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

i just saw ludwiguer answer his answer might be more useful